# When using RDKIT, object is not iterable error appears

Tags: python, rdkit

I am trying to use tanimoto similarity to compare molecular fingerprints using rdkit. I am trying to compare the two items in list 1 with the one item in list 2. However, I get getting an error. I do not understand it because I have anything named "Mol" in my code. Does anyone have any advice? Thank you

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdFingerprintGenerator
from rdkit.Chem import DataStructs
mol1 = ('CCO', 'CCOO')
mol2 = ('CC')
fii = Chem.MolFromSmiles(mol2)
fpgen1 = rdFingerprintGenerator.GetMorganGenerator(radius=2)
fps1 = [fpgen1.GetFingerprint(m) for m in fii]
for m in mol1:
    fi = Chem.MolFromSmiles(m)
    fpgen2 = rdFingerprintGenerator.GetMorganGenerator(radius=2)
    fps2 = [fpgen2.GetFingerprint(m) for m in fi]
    for x in fsp2:
        t = DataStructs.TanimotoSimilarity(fps1, fps2(x))
        print(t)
```

ERROR:
fps1 = [fpgen1.GetFingerprint(m) for m in fii]
TypeError: 'Mol' object is not iterable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The `Mol` object is the name of the rdkit class that is returned when you call `Chem.MolFromSmiles`, not one of your variable names.
- The error says that the `Mol` object is not iterable (it is a single molecule)

```
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdFingerprintGenerator
from rdkit.Chem import DataStructs

smiles1 = ('CCO', 'CCOO')
smiles2 = ('CC',)

mols1 = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi) for smi in smiles1]
mols2 = [Chem.MolFromSmiles(smi) for smi in smiles2]

# you only need to instantiate the generator once, you can use it for both lists
fpgen = rdFingerprintGenerator.GetMorganGenerator(radius=2)

fps1 = [fpgen.GetFingerprint(m) for m in mols1]
fps2 = [fpgen.GetFingerprint(m) for m in mols2]

# if you only care about the single entry in fps2 you can just index it
for n, fp in enumerate(fps1):
    t = DataStructs.TanimotoSimilarity(fp, fps2[0])
    print(n, t)
```

Comment: Just a quick heads up, the smiles2 tuple should be constructed with a comma i.e. ('CC',) else mols2 will contain two methane mols rather than a single ethane mol

Comment: Good catch! Incidentally I wasn't even aware that MolFromSmiles accepted multiple inputs before this question was posted, hence why I separated out the list comprehension

Comment: Hello. I am tried this code and it worked besides the fact that when I try to print the individual values of the similarities I get a “float object not iterable” error. Whenever I use ‘for x in t:’ I get that error. Is there a way to make it a list instead because I can’t iterate over it. Thanks.

Comment: This code snippet does print the individual values in the line `print(n, t)`. Each `t` is a single tanimoto similarity value and therefore can't be iterated